# Show Alert message and redirect after click Ok

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, redirect, alert

I am Using redirect function of Codeigniter with alert of JavaScript. I want to display message first before redirect to other page, but my code just directly redirect the page without displaying alert message. I need code in method of controller of codeigniter.I used code as follows in method of controller:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Duplicate Users')</script>";
redirect('auth/login'),'location');
```

Plz Advice me
Waiting for Response
Thank You very Much for supporting me.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684140/codeigniter-javascript-alert-with-success-message-on-click-ok-page-refresh

Comment: Because server code fires before clientside code! Why don't design the page so that the serverside login page can handle that situation. AKA pass param to it and on that page if param exists, show the message.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825283/redirect-to-a-page-url-after-alert-button-is-pressed

Comment: Answer Post on above link not working

Comment: Please don't use JavaScript alert(). It makes baby Jesus cry.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747316/php-alert-message) ..

Server code `(PHP -> redirect)` is fired up before Client Code `(JS -> alert)`. There are several solutions to this but the easiest one is to use one type of code for the functionality (either PHP or JS) ..

Let's use PHP to fire up JS for now, since that's what you're using ..

```
echo "<script>alert('Duplicate Users') ; window.location.href = 'auth/login'</script>"
```

Comment: I try using javascript code but also not shown alert message

Comment: And Multiple Redirect process execute

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  alert("Duplicate Users");
  window.location.href = "auth/login";
</script>
```